# how to test the result of an API without requesting it

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I've got a function like:

```
def request_API(request_url):  #To test
    fail_request = -1
    response = requests.get(request_url)
    if response.ok:
        infos = json.loads(response.text)
        if infos.has_key("movie"):
            return  infos["movie"]
        if infos.has_key("tvseries"):
            return  infos["tvseries"]

    print "Allocine API Request Error"
    return fail_request
```

I did a test like:

```
def test_should_fail_to_request(self):
        #GIVEN
        response = json.dumps({"error":{"code":0,"$":"No result"}})
        requests.get = mock.MagicMock(return_value=response)

        #WHEN
        response = my_mod.request_allocine_API("") #requests mocked so we don't need an URL

        #THEN
        self.assertEqual(response, -1, "There should be an error in the API")
```

But I've got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ok'
```

I know it come from the fact that when I mock request.get I return a JSON. My question is what is the proper way to do it. Have I to recreate an object requests or is there more simple way to do so.

Comment: try:  `if response.status_code == 200` or `response.status_code == requests.codes.ok` instead of `if response.ok`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mocking `requests.get`, which normally returns an `Response` object, to instead return a plain string. Try having it return an `Response` object instead:

```
from mock import patch
from requests import Response


def test_should_fail_to_request(self):
    mock_response = Response()
    mock_response.status_code = 404
    mock_response.body = json.dumps({"error":{"code":0,"$":"No result"}})

    with patch('requests.get', return_value=mock_response):
        response = my_mod.request_allocine_API("")

    self.assertEqual(response, -1, "There should be an error in the API")
```

Comment: I've got the following error: ImportError: cannot import name HttpResponse

Comment: Sorry about that, had a typo with the casing, it's `HTTPResponse`, not `HttpResponse`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Updated again to use `Response`, not `HTTPResponse`, since that's more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I use requests-mock library which works well.

the document is in : https://requests-mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

The best feature is supporting for regex.